# datepicker wont work after disabling month and year to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've been stuck on this for more than 4 hours. I want only to select months with the arrows then when I press the show button ajax operation will start (I'm ok with this).

Example & code here:

```
$(function() {
$('.dp').datepicker( {

    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    dateFormat: 'mm-yy',


    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    }
});
});
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VgbR/16/).

Comment: I haven't used this but disabling mm and yy and choosing a dateFormat as 'mm-yy'?

Comment: You are really using jquery 1.4.1?

Comment: If you want to select only months with Arrows, why are you disabling month?

Comment: oh sorry, i'm using 1.10.3/jquery-ui.js and jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: Yea this is irrational :) You are setting date format to month and year only and disable selecton of those. No wonder it does not work.

Comment: @VangaSasidhar when i disable months i disable a dropdown menu not the arrows

Comment: What exactly doesn't work then?

Comment: im getting the value "date" and send it to AJAX request. But if i move  only arrows the value always stays on the today date.

Comment: This is because You disallow to change month and year. The thing u are selecting is only a view of month and year in widget, but the only date You can select is today, as You disabled day selection so it keeps default day in default month in default year. Default is today. Normally all other days would be greyed out but You don't show days.

Comment: @FlashThunder OK i removed this 2 rows and set the date to  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",  and still getting the today date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.dp').datepicker( {

        showButtonPanel: false,
        dateFormat: 'mm-yy-dd',

        onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month){
            $('#current').html('Month: '+month+' Year: '+year);
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tSAXf/1/

To send it via ajax for example You could change part of code to:

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(year,month){
    $('#current').html('Month: '+month+' Year: '+year);
    $('#current').attr('rel','month='+month+'&year='+year);
}
```

And add button to site:

```
<button id="datesubmit">Save this date</button>
```

And an action to this button:

```
$('#datesubmit').click(function(){
    var datesubmit = this;
    if($(datesubmit).attr('Disabled')) return false;
    $(datesubmit).attr('Disabled','Disabled');
    $.post('/my_php_script.php',$('#current').attr('rel'),function(){
        alert('We did it! Date sent!');
        $(datesubmit).removeAttr('Disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: excuse me but i'm new to jquery.
How to get params from this function(year,month)
and send them with ajax?
Thanks

Comment: Edited to answer Your question.

Comment: cool that works but when i'm trying to see the results from $_POST
on my_php_script.php with
var_dump($_POST); 
i get: array(0) {)
No Properties

Comment: ah it should of course be `$.post('/my_php_script.php',$('#current').attr('rel'),function(){...`

Comment: i just add class='current' to <span id="current"> and it works.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is this option: `onChangeMonthYear`

You can use it the following way:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dp').datepicker( {
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', 
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month) { 
           //you'll get the current year and month selected
           //do whatever you want here with year and month vars
        }
    });
});
```

More docs here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear